# How to avoid multiple 'libFoo.so' open() calls at application launch?

Tags: c, strace

I have the next so file in */UNI/System/Libs/libmbedcrypto.so.3* directory. When I launch my application, that use *libmbedcrypto.so.3* with [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) I see:

```
open("/UNI/System/Libs/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libmbedcrypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/UNI/System/Libs/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7ef80610) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/UNI/System/Libs/tls/v7l/neon/libmbedcrypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/UNI/System/Libs/tls/v7l/neon", 0x7ef80610) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/UNI/System/Libs/tls/v7l/vfp/libmbedcrypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/UNI/System/Libs/tls/v7l/vfp", 0x7ef80610) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/UNI/System/Libs/tls/v7l/libmbedcrypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

//...   more stat64 & open

open("/UNI/System/Libs/libmbedcrypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/UNI/System/Libs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

How do I get rid of all the open & stat64 calls?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of those? That's normal.

Comment: Remove those directories from LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Though what you're seeing is not really a problem, this is working as intended, that's how library name resolution works in Unix/Linux... Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: I know the location of the so file, I want my app to go there first in order to start faster (one core, a lot of process starting at once)

Comment: @NoamM Then you'll have to not use a C library... Write it all in assembly if that's what you want. I mean, the amount of time that is lost with those filesystem checks is negligible.

Comment: @ forest, I thought there is a compiler flag or something that will resolve it.

Comment: You can always create a container with a filesystructure such that the lookup magically finds the lib at first try ...

Comment: @Bananguin It'll still run a dozen unnecessary syscalls. Not that it actually matters...

Comment: You could try compiling with `-rpath` to the linker and not putting loads of directories into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or equivalent, and possibly use `patchelf` to `--shrink-rpath` the `RPATH` down to size, but I'm not sure how or why all those directories are being wandered through, or how the various libraries are being compiled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is normal.** You actually cannot get rid of this without rewriting the program from scratch in assembly, or by writing your own C library to go with it. This is all standard for pretty much any program. Seriously, you do not need to optimize something as inconsequential as this. The amount of time wasted by attempting to access non-existent files is negligible, as you can see in the below syscall trace of `true`, a program designed only to return 0, from an embedded system:

```
root@UP-1044:~# strace -T -e trace=open true
open("/tmp/t/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000643>
open("/tmp/t/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000861>
open("/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000208>
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The amount of time wasted on each of these syscalls seems to be less than a single millisecond!